[Monitoring and Alerts Configuration for Google reCAPTCHA v3 Enterprise Edition]
0
I am reaching out for technical assistance regarding our implementation of Google reCAPTCHA v3 Enterprise Edition. We have successfully created keys for our sites and are now looking to set up monitoring for daily API usage.
We aim to track and monitor the daily request volumes to the reCAPTCHA service and set up alerts based on certain usage thresholds. Could you provide detailed information on how we can configure these aspects within our management console? Additionally, we would be interested in knowing if there is a specific dashboard or tool that allows us to manage these settings efficiently.
I would appreciate any documentation or step-by-step guide you could provide to facilitate this process.
Thank you for your time and I look forward to your prompt response.
We have successfully created keys for our sites and are now looking to set up monitoring for daily API usage.
